# How to deal with the problem of TS2367 error after the replacement code?

Tags: rollup

I use rollup-replace as the variable switch of the builder in the project, but I have encountered a problem when using it with TypeScript, and I always give me errors like this:

> semantic error TS2367: This condition will always return'true' since the types'boolean' and'string' have no overlap.

I will write code like this in my code

```js
// a.ts
import Prod from './prod';
import Pre from './pre';
If(process.env.PROD === ’true’){
  console.log(‘is prod’);
  Prod.init();
} else {
  console.log(‘is pre’);
  Pre.init();
}
```

```js
// rollup.config.js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

export default [
{
  input: 'src/a.ts',
  output: { file: 'dist/a.js', format: 'iife' },
  plugins: [
      replace({ values: { 'process.env.PROD': JSON.stringify(true) }, preventAssignment: true }),
      resolve({ browser: true }),
      commonjs(),
      typescript(),
  ]
}
]
```

In the above build code, `replace` needs to precede `resolve`, because it is necessary to use `replace` to avoid useless JS from being `imported` into the bundle file.

Who can help me solve this meaningless error message?

Answer (score 0):

In the rollup document, I found the advanced usage of [treeshake.moduleSideEffects](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#treeshake), which talked about the ability I want to achieve.

```js
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import replace from '@rollup/plugin-replace';

export default [
  {
    input: 'src/a.ts',
    output: { file: 'dist/a.js', format: 'iife' },
    plugins: [
        replace({ values: { 'process.env.PROD': JSON.stringify(true) }, preventAssignment: true }),
        resolve({ browser: true }),
        commonjs(),
        typescript(),
    ],
    treeshake: {
      moduleSideEffects: false, // Prune unused pure external imports
    },
  }
]
```